# Trying to update transient variable in a hibernate data object for use in a controller, but it's not displaying (in spring mvc)

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, transient

I'm using hibernate to pull data from two different tables and use them to display. Table A has personnel data, and data B has some state-changing data. Rather than use two lists to display, I want to take a variable from B, apply it to entries pulled from A via a transient variable, and use it in a controller for display.

What I'm seeing is that when I use it in System.out, the value is displayed correctly. however, when I step through with the debugger, it's not showing the correct value (ie: a boolean value that I have in there is defaulted as false, but something in Table B sets it to true under certain conditions. Sys out shows the value get reset to true, but when I step through with debugger, I don't see it set to true).

Further, when I pass it to the jsp (via model) to then trigger a checkbox, the boolean is still false, so the checkbox remains unchecked.

I've had issues in the past where hibernate pulls don't work right when used to set another value, due to lazy loading iirc. Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you please add some code? Simple descriptions of it do not help us help you. thanks!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.